# Packet forwarding event in Contiki

Tags: c, contiki, contiki-ng

I am doing some work on worm-attack detection in RPL. In RPL, the communication between the clients might be multiple hops, with the packets going through many nodes.

However, only the receiver gets a `tcpip_event` on reception of the packet. The nodes that the route passes through do not get this event. Is there any way to detect the packet on the intermediate nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get a notification or callback when a packet is forwarded. However, you can get a callback when a packet is received or sent by the lower layers.

In Contiki, use the function `rime_sniffer_add` for that. Check `apps/powertrace/powertrace.c` for an example.

In Contiki-NG the function has been [renamed](https://contiki-ng.readthedocs.io/en/release-v4.5/_api/netstack_8h_source.html) to `netstack_sniffer_add`.

**Usage example:**

Declare the sniffer like this, in the global scope:

```
RIME_SNIFFER(packet_sniffer, input_packet, output_packet);
```

Then add the sniffer from your code, once, at the start of the application execution:

```
rime_sniffer_add(&packet_sniffer);
```

The functions `input_packet` and `output_packets` are callbacks defined by you and can be used to examine the packets; for example, like this:

```
static void
input_packet(void)
{
  int rssi = (int)packetbuf_attr(PACKETBUF_ATTR_RSSI);
  printf("received a packet with RSSI=%d\n", rssi);
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. I have read the code 'powertrace.c'. I think the function rime_sniffer_add put the rime_sniffer into the LIST. So when packet received or sent by a node, I need to add a rime_sniffer into the LIST and then check the LIST?  I am still not clear how to do it. Can you give me a further hints or a short brief code?